# MongoDB complex aggregation pipeline of Age fields

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that may have zero or more of the following fields: `DOB` (date of birth), `YOB` (year of birth) and `Age`. These may contain integers, floats or strings, and they may or may not be mappable to real values. For instance:

```
{'_id': id1, 'Age': 25},
{'_id': id2, 'Age': 'unknown', 'DOB': 'xxxx-xx-xx'},
{'_id': id3, 'Age': '8', 'DOB': '1988/01/05'},
{'_id': id4, 'YOB': '1995.0'},
{'_id': id5, 'DOB': '5/8/1886'},
{'_id': id6, 'Age': 17, 'YOB': 2003},
{'_id': id7},
...
```

For each document in the database, I need to extract a single standardized field, `Age_Standardized`, with the following criteria:

1. is an integer
2. is > 12
3. is < 99

I also need to implement an order of preference in the event multiple of the fields have a viable value, as DOB then YOB then Age.

So, for instance, if `Age` = 17 but `DOB` = '1900', `Age_Standardized` = 17 because, even though DOB exists (and is preferred to Age), it produces an Age_Standardized outside of the viable range (13-98).

If `YOB` = '1998.0' and `Age` = '19' then `Age_Standardized` = 23 because, even though Age exists and is viable, YOB is preferred and also viable.

I need to implement all of this over a large collection, and I was hoping to do it within a single PyMongo aggregation framework. In the examples above, the output would be:

```
{'_id': id1, 'Age': 25, 'Age_Standardized': 25},
{'_id': id2, 'Age': 'unknown', 'DOB': 'xxxx-xx-xx'},
{'_id': id3, 'Age': '8', 'DOB': '1988/01/05', 'Age_Standardized': 33},
{'_id': id4, 'YOB': '1995.0', 'Age_Standardized': 26},
{'_id': id5, 'DOB': '5/8/1886'},
{'_id': id6, 'Age': 17, 'YOB': 2003, 'Age_Standardized': 18},
{'_id': id7},
```

Comment: age field type and DOB field values and format are inconsistent, so this is not a good idea to do these type of operations in query. i would suggest you do correct all fields type and date format to standardize format, otherwise your query will not give performance in large collection.

Comment: Another proof that you should **never** store date values as stings. Store always proper `Date` objects.